# php mysql real_escape_string for whole query

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to escape a whole query instead of each searched field. For example I know I can do it like this:

```
$name="O'Connor";
$email="mark.O'Connor@something.com";

$name=mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($email);

$query =("SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Name = '$name' OR Email = '$email' ");

// code to run query here
```

What I am looking for is a way to build my query string like this :

```
$query=("SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Name = '$name' OR Email = '$email' ");
$query=mysql_real_escape_string($query); // Can I escape the whole Query ??

// code to run query here
```

My reason for asking this Is I have a complex query which is using at around 15 variables from a form and I want to clean them all at once instead of using loads of mysql_real_escape($vairableName)...

Is this possible and can anyone exlplain how I can acheive this

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should rather escape `none` of the query and read about prepared statements. Don't sprinkle sugar over ... :). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Also, read http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-can-i-explain-sql-injection-without-technical-jargon/25710#25710 and ask yourself this question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, using prepared statements is the best way to go. But in case you still want to proceed ahead, you can do something like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
   // this will take care of escaping all form elements
   $$key = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}
```

So if your form contains 3 elements whose names are `abc`, `def`, and `ghi`, the above code will create variables named as `$abc`, `$def`, and `$ghi` respectively.

Then you can use them in query as before:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Name = '$abc' OR Email = '$def'";
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining so well Asprin, Really helped me out I will look at the foreach option first then look to use prepared statments in the future , thanks again to all who helped

Comment: mysql*. Do not use mysql_real_escape_string, use: mysqli_real_escape_string instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. Escaping changes characters with special meaning in SQL into escape sequences. You **need** some characters with special meaning so that the query can work. If you could just escape the entire query, then all database drivers would just do that automatically.

e.g.

```
$foo = "John O'Reilly";
$sql = "WHERE name='$foo'";
# There are three ' characters here, but only the middle one should be escaped
```

That said, you should stop using [an **obsolete** database API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and pick a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) that supports [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) which will save you from having to call `real_escape_string` all over the place.